# Where do I put base_footprint?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-link, robot-pose-ekf, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have a urdf for my robot, with the tree root as `base_link`.

However, I am using `robot_pose_ekf`, which has a hard-coded transform for `base_footprint`. Assuming a simple square `base_footprint`, should I make it the root:

```
base_footprint
  base_link ... rest of model
```

EDIT:

After adding a base_footprint link and joint to base_link:

```
robot name is: Thumperbot_Simplistic
---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
root Link: base_footprint has 1 child(ren)
    child(1):  base_link
```

I still get the following error:

```
Node: /robot_pose_ekf
Time: 12:35:35.441279569 (2014-09-16)
Severity: Debug
Published Topics: /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined, /rosout, /tf

Could not transform imu message from base_link to base_footprint. Imu will not be activated yet.

Location:
/tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-robot-pose-ekf-1.11.11-0trusty-20140805-0105/src/odom_estimation_node.cpp:OdomEstimationNode::imuCallback:234

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Perhaps it is not receiving my urdf that have in the launchfile?  Here is the launchfile:

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find thumperbot_description)/urdf/thumperbot_description.urdf" />
  <node name="gps_conv" pkg="gps_common" type="utm_odometry_node">
    <remap from="odom" to="vo" />
    <remap from="fix" to="/gps/fix" />
    <param name="rot_covariance" value="99999" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="base_link" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <rosparam>
      odom_used: false
      imu_used: true
      vo_used: true
      debug: true
      self_dignose: true
    </rosparam>
  </node>
  <include file="$(find piksi_driver)/launch/piksi_driver.launch" />
  <include file="$(find razor_imu)/launch/razor-pub.launch"/>
</launch>
```

Here razor_imu and piksi_driver are drivers for the razor imu sensor and the piksi gps sensor. Both sensors output their data correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192737/where-do-i-put-base_footprint?/) by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2014-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes! base_footprint is located directly under your base_link at ground level. See this answer:

http://answers.ros.org/question/12770/base_link-to-base_footprint-transform/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-09-16**:
This doesn't appear to work, Wolf. Could you take a look at my launchfile and see if there's anything glaringly obvious? Otherwise I'm going into robot_pose_ekf source...

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-09-17**:
You could check your tf tree by 'rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree' or 'rosrun tf view_frames'... Does it look properly? Are all frames connected?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-09-17**:
You seen to use URDF. Are robot_state_publisher and joint_state_publisher running properly?

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-09-17**:
Bingo Wolf! Was missing robot_state_publisher and joint_state_publisher from the launchfile. Thanks!